# How do i split a string of jsonObjects into an array

Tags: java, android, json

I'm getting some data from the Trello API over HTTP. So an example of the response would be:

```
'[{"name":"asd","desc":"yes"},{"name":"xyz","desc":"no"}]'
```

I'm using the volley library for making the request and getting the response. Is there a way for me to get the response in the form of json objects directly instead of in a string?

If not how should I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: probably there is, but what is preventing you to instantiate a JSONArray ?

Comment: one minute googling for: `volley json`  https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json

Comment: i could not really understand your question , but in Spring we create a model class with the fields "name" and "desc" with setter and getter. Ant We can use annotation to indicate to Spring to map json to the model. I dont know if it has helped but if u want i can give more information.

Comment: What strings? "name", "asd", "desc", "yes"? Please elaborate what you want to do.

Comment: Why dont you just parse the string in json array and get the json objects from it.

Comment: I did not know about JSONArray. Sorry. Could this question please be closed?

Comment: @guy You should mark the answer by alican.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `JSONArray()`. And then you can use `getString()` so you can use all string function.

Example code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
int i = 0;
while (i <jsonArray.length()) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonObj.getString("name");
    String description = jsonObj.getString("desc");
    //TODO create your Java object and store these strings into it.
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Sufian thanks:)
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(responseString);
String res = reader.getString("TAG");

Like JSONArray.

Comment: Thank  you  :) It is better.

Answer (score 2):

use volley can solve easily.

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
             //the response is JsonArray       
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
});
```